# Unable launch instant app from AS on phone

Tags: android-instant-apps

I want to debug my instant app from the android studio, but cannot:

1. try using [the default configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LEny.png) for the instant app, but get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqhJZ.png)
2. try using terminal by `ia run instantapp-debug.zip` (ia - jar from extras folder) or `adb install-multiple -r -t --instantapp *.apk`, but in both cases get the error **db: failed to install \extras\google\instantapps\tools\apks\release\supervisor_armeabi-v7a.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]**

can anyone help me this it?

Versions: Android Studio 3.1.3, gradle plugin 3.3.0-alpha02, gradle version 4.8, ia sdk 1.3.0

PS: instant app published and work fine in store (now in an internal test)

PS2: ia can be deployed to another phone. So the problem only with a specific phone.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? How about your device and Android build? The msg indicates it wants to install the Google Play Services for instant apps, so your device is pre-O?

Comment: Also, have you checked your SDK manager to see if the Instant Apps Development SDK is up-to-date? 1.3.0?

Comment: @TWL : AS 3.1.3, gradle plugin 3.3.0-alpha02, gradle version 4.8, ia sdk 1.3.0

Comment: @TWL phone Samsung J5 (os 7.0). As I say all works fine from store (so all versions are correct). Problem only in tries to debug ia from studio / console.

Comment: On this particular phone, go to Settings > Apps, and look for Google Play Services for Instant Apps - uninstall it. Immediately after, you might see a notification asking you to restore it, do it. Now try building from your AS again. If it still doesn't work, uninstall it again, but this time, don't restore it, just build from AS so that AS will install it instead.

Comment: @TWL
thx, this is works now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this issue, make sure you have the newest version of the Google Play Instant Development SDK (at least SDK 1.5).

You can find it in the Tools > Android > SDK Manager > SDK Tools. Check the box next to the Google Play Instant SDK and apply the upgrade.